# Backup blog posts only

Tags: installation, backup

I have a Wordpress site with a lot of pages and blog posts. I want to create a new site but keep all blog posts, just blog posts and no pages.

How can I achieve this? When I backup the database from mysql, everthing will pass to the new site, but I just want to backup blog posts.

[WordPress Backups](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups)

Comment: Simply use a plugin for this kind of work, like the following plugins: - [WP Database Backup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-database-backup/) - [WP-DB-Backup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-db-backup/) See also: [How To Backup Your WordPress Blog In Three Easy Steps](http://www.problogger.net/archives/2009/10/10/how-to-backup-your-wordpress-blog-in-three-easy-steps/). This article can help you understand this process

Answer (score 4):

On your old site go to Tools > Export in the admin area.

You can select what you want to export. In your case "Posts." Click `Download Export File`

On the new site you'll go to:

```
Tools > Import > WordPress
```

*You'll have to hit a button to install the **core** plugin, but you can remove it after the import.*

Import the file you downloaded from the old site.

Comment: of-course your way is much better but i think he is a newbie and doesn't get this kind of way ;)

Comment: I think if he knows how to backup his database, then this is far more simple ;)